# Python networkx optimal distances between nodes and labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, formatting, networkx

I'm using Python's [networkx](https://networkx.org/) to plot a network diagram that shows roughly 30 connections between different items.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

de = pd.DataFrame(data={'x1':['species 90900','species 90900','species 90900','species 90900','species 45020','species 51190','species 87823','species 51190','species\n12990','species 47743','species A','species\n12990','species 55698','species 55698','species 51190','species 55698','species\n12990','species 55045','species B','species 09088','species B','species 55045','species 68650','species 63620','species 55045','species 55698','species 09088','species 33500'],
                        'x2':['species 40399','species 95663','species 70000','species 01221','species 87823','species 87823','species 60023','species 90900','species 90900','species 90900','species 33500','species 47743','species 90900','species 90900','species 63620','species 11924','species 63620','species A','species 90900','species A','species 63620','species\n12990','species 09088','species 90900','species 09088','species 09088','species 90900','species\n12990']})
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(de, source='x1', target='x2')

# count no. unique instances to determine nodesize
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = pd.concat([de['x1'],de['x2']])
df['count'] = 1
d = df.groupby('name')['count'].sum().to_dict()
for node in G.nodes:
    d.setdefault(node, 1)
nodes, values = zip(*d.items())

cmap = []
for i in nodes:
    # different colours for different species
    if (i=='species A') | (i=='species B'):
        # species of interest
        cmap.append("lightblue")
    else: 
        cmap.append("lightgreen")

# pos = nx.fruchterman_reingold_layout(G)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=1.5, scale=2, iterations=50)
# pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G)
# pos = nx.spiral_layout(G)
# pos = nx.spectral_layout(G)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, nodelist=list(nodes), node_size=[v*200 for v in values], node_color=cmap, edge_color='gray', font_color='k', font_size=10, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

I tried to use [`spring_layout`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html) and other functions to organize the nodes and labels so that they don't touch. I don't want to make the label text too small or the `figsize` too big. It looks like I'll have to manually make adjustments to the `pos` argument to make the figure look decent, which is not ideal.

Is there a better way to organize the graph so that the graph makes better use of the empty space? How do I ensure that the labels don't overlap? Is there an efficient way to force a linebreak when the label is too long (without editing the original dataframe)?

[image: network]

Comment: Seems good to me when the figure window is maximized.

Comment: but not when you save it as a figure, `plt.savefig('mygraph.pdf')`

Comment: are the `nx.spring_layout` parameters not able to create enough space between nodes? I would think it should be possible to tune those until the nodes don't overlap for your desired figsize.

Comment: @aorr I tried adjusting the `spring_layout` parameters but there are still overlaps and large sections of white space - the figure in my post is pretty much the best I could do

Comment: you could try differential edge weights to make the problematic nodes more/less attractive, but that'd require a change to the df, and you mention that may not be possible. I see you also explored other layouts, but maybe not nx.pydot_layout? The `dot` and 'neato' layouts/progs from graphviz are pretty good options, but they may come with some dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The lowest hanging fruit is replacing `species X` with just `X` as the `species` prefix carries no information.

> How do I ensure that the labels don't overlap?

Networkx has no functionality that removes collisions between labels and nodes or edges. If you are open to using other packages, you can use my [`netgraph`](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph) library, which attempts to reduce these collisions if you specify a scalar offset of the label from their respective nodes. Netgraph accepts networkx graphs as inputs (as well as a variety of other formats) so incorporating it in your workflow should be simple. You example looks like this with netgraph:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

from netgraph import Graph # pip install netgraph / conda install -c conda-forge netgraph

de = pd.DataFrame(data={'x1':['species 90900','species 90900','species 90900','species 90900','species 45020','species 51190','species 87823','species 51190','species 12990','species 47743','species A','species 12990','species 55698','species 55698','species 51190','species 55698','species 12990','species 55045','species B','species 09088','species B','species 55045','species 68650','species 63620','species 55045','species 55698','species 09088','species 33500'],
                        'x2':['species 40399','species 95663','species 70000','species 01221','species 87823','species 87823','species 60023','species 90900','species 90900','species 90900','species 33500','species 47743','species 90900','species 90900','species 63620','species 11924','species 63620','species A','species 90900','species A','species 63620','species 12990','species 09088','species 90900','species 09088','species 09088','species 90900','species 12990']})

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(de, source='x1', target='x2')

# count no. unique instances to determine nodesize
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = pd.concat([de['x1'],de['x2']])
df['count'] = 1
d = df.groupby('name')['count'].sum().to_dict()
for node in G.nodes:
    d.setdefault(node, 1)
nodes, values = zip(*d.items())

cmap = []
for i in nodes:
    # different colours for different species
    if (i=='species A') | (i=='species B'):
        # species of interest
        cmap.append("lightblue")
    else:
        cmap.append("lightgreen")

node_size = d
node_color = dict(zip(nodes, cmap))
node_labels = {node : node.replace('species ', '') for node in nodes}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
plot = Graph(G, node_layout='spring', node_layout_kwargs=dict(k=0.15), scale=(2,2),
             node_size=node_size, node_color=node_color, edge_color='gray',
             node_labels=node_labels, node_label_fontdict=dict(size=10), node_label_offset=0.1,
             ax=ax)

# if the node is large, place node label centered on node position
for node in nodes:
    if node_size[node] > 5:
        plot.node_label_artists[node].set_position(plot.node_positions[node])
plt.show()
```